# Python 3- Tkinter destroy() not working for dynamic checkbuttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My code gets a computer name then looks through folders and pulls these folders' names to create checkboxes, then it shows them to the user so they can select the ones to work with. However, if you change the computer name I want to delete all the current checkboxes' names, and display the new names from the new computer name. I  have tried destroy() in multiple ways, but it just doesn't work. I know it has to do with working with grids.

```
def CreateBoxes(folders):

    if len(checkBoxList) != 0: #if there are already checkboxes then delete
        for i in folders:
            chk.destroy()

    count=0
    for i in folders: #Creates checkbuttons for each folder received
        checkBoxList[i]=IntVar()
        chk = Checkbutton(window, text=str(i), variable=checkBoxList[i])
        chk.grid(row=0+count,column=4)
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `chk.destroy()` executes, Python does not understand what `chk` refers to. You may have created a variable named `chk` in an earlier execution of that function, but that name ceased to exist after the function returned.

One possible solution is to keep an external reference to each of your checkboxes. Then you will be able to access each one at a later time and destroy them.

```
checkboxes = []

def CreateBoxes(folders):
    if len(checkBoxList) != 0: #if there are already checkboxes then delete
        for chk in checkboxes:
            chk.destroy()
        checkboxes.clear()

    count=0
    for i in folders: #Creates checkbuttons for each folder received
        checkBoxList[i]=IntVar()
        chk = Checkbutton(window, text=str(i), variable=checkBoxList[i])
        chk.grid(row=0+count,column=4)
        checkboxes.append(chk)
        count += 1
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, I have to practice more with creating list to reference later like you did. I appreciate your help Kevin!